# How do you add columns from a spreadsheet and then generate percentages in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, sum

I have a lot of data in a format like this

```
Amistad Academy District Amistad Academy    596 812 73.4
Andover School District  Andover            39  334 11.7
Ansonia School District  Ansonia High School    427 732 58.3
Ansonia School District  Ansonia Middle School  219 458 47.8
Ansonia School District  Mead School            431 642 67.1
Ansonia School District  Prendergast School 504 787 64
```

What I need to do is grep a bunch of school districts and then take the last column, sum up all the matching districts (all of Ansonia for example) then divide that number by the sum of the next-to-last column.  I have no trouble getting the school districts into separate files.  That was just a grep.  Now, however, I'm stuck and thinking it might be easier to just do it in excel.  I've been playing with solutions in perl like

```
  1 #!/opt/local/bin/perl
  2 use strict;
  3 use warnings;
  4 use ARGV::readonly;
  5 
  6 my @data;
  7 my @headers - split ',', <>;
  8 
  9 while (<>) {
 10   my @row = split;
 11   $data[$_] += $row[$_] for (0 .. $#row);
 12 }
 13 
 14 $" = "\t";
 15 print "@headers", "\n";
 16 print "@data";
```

but can't figure out the syntax to do the sum and division.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this homework? We have no problem to helping with homework, but please specify if it is we can adjust our answers accordingly.

Comment: Not homework.  My wife is a researcher for an educational foundation.  I foolishly told her this would be much easier with a simple script.

Comment: @edward: don't worry: I shall tell her it was all your own work :)

Answer (score 1):

You are summing every column. You just want to sum two of them. Otherwise, you're practically there.

```
my $sum_last = 0;  # Use better name.
my $sum_penu = 0;  # Use better name.
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   my @row = split /\t/;
   next if $row[0] ne 'Ansonia School District';
   $sum_last += $row[-1];
   $sum_penu += $row[-2];
}

say $sum_last / $sum_penu;
```

Answer (score 0):

The program below will pick out the values from the file and keep the running totals for each school district in a hash. The contents of the hash are printed when all the data has been read. It works from the unfiltered file - you don't have to grep it into separate sources.

I notice that your data seems to be tab-separated, and it is important to use `split /\t/` so that fields containing space characters don't get split up as well.

You don't say what the data means so I can't make the code more readable.

Please ask again if you have any further questions.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'myfile' or die $!;

scalar <$fh>; # lose header record

my %data;

while (<$fh>) {
  my @fields = split /\t/;
  my $district = shift @fields;
  $data{$district}[0] += $fields[-2];
  $data{$district}[1] += $fields[-1];
}

for my $district (sort keys %data) {
  printf "%s - %f\n", $district, $data{$district}[1] / $data{$district}[0];
}
```

**output**

```
Andover School District - 0.035030
Ansonia School District - 0.090569
```

Comment: Hmm, this is not producing errors but it is not producing anything else either.  I changed myfile to the correct filename but it does not seem to be producing any output.  I think this is the awnser though.  I'll keep at it.

Comment: You should do some debugging. `print "@fields\n"` inside the loop to see what you are reading. Have you copied the code exactly? Without the `scalar` the `<$fh>` will eat all of the data and leave nothing for the loop.